# How to programatically generate fstring format spec?

Tags: python, string, format

How can I programmatically generate an f-string [format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)? For example I'd like to zero pad this binary number up to `n` bits:

```
>> n = 5 
>> f"{6:05b}"
00110    
>> n = 7 
>> f"{6:07b}"
0000110
```

Comment: an hybrid approach `int(6).__format__(f'0{n}b'))` to separate the formatting part, [`format_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), from the object to be formatted

Answer (score 1):

Nested formatting works with f-strings as it did with the older `format` function, as detailed in the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) section of the docs:

> A format_spec field can also include nested replacement fields within it. These nested replacement fields may contain a field name, conversion flag and format specification, but deeper nesting is not allowed. The replacement fields within the format_spec are substituted before the format_spec string is interpreted. This allows the formatting of a value to be dynamically specified.

Sadly, the docs don't include an example with f-strings. Here's one. Notice the nested curly braces:

```
for n in range(3, 8):
    print(f"{6:0{n}b}")
```

Prints:

```
110
0110
00110
000110
0000110
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? with f-string the access to the outer scope is "explicit", you don't care about field-names, ... anymore. Instead, with `format` are helpful since provide a way to get terms outside the string

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining the f-string to be the result of a function. This will delay its evaluation until the function is called:

```
template = lambda: f"{6:0{n}b}"

n = 5
print(template())  # -> 00110
n = 7
print(template())  # -> 0000110
```